# Call one ajax call after another - React on click function

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to restart a service. For that I have to execute 2 API calls.
First cancel and then run.

I am trying to execute these 2 POST Ajax calls by binding the run inside the success of cancel call as a callback. But its giving me error and doesnt refresh the browser on success. When I execute only one call "run" it works fine and the page is reloaded as well.

FYI : These are POST Ajax calls.

```
    onClickRestart(params, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    var {
        pipelineName,e
    } = params;

    const url1 = `/api/${params}/cancel`;
    const url2 =`/api/${params}/run`
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url1,
        processData: false,
        async:false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: (response) => {
            if(!response.error) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url2,
                    processData: false,
                    async:false,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: (response) => {
                        if(!response.error) {
                            location.reload(true);
                        }
                    },
                    error: (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

What is my mistake ?

Comment: "it's giving me error"... are you going to tell us or would you like us to guess until we get it right?

Comment: P.S. `async:false` is deprecated and should not be used, also you can expect it to stop working at some time in future. It locks the browser UI during requests and makes a bad user experience. Anyway, you don't even need it here since you're using callbacks correctly to handle your responses.

Comment: gives me error as 404 not found.

Comment: Yes @ADyson I removed that. I actually tried 2 ajax separate calls that time I added it.

Comment: If you're getting a 404 Not Found, then in that case you have provided the wrong URL. You need to check your server code/settings to ensure you provide a correct URL. We can't help you with that, based on the info you've given here.

Comment: The URL is correct. As I can run them separately.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. Nothing about the way you've written the code above would cause the URL variables to be altered between the two requests. Have you double-checked that the ajax call is calling the URL you expected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188706/discussion-between-user3594118-and-adyson).